# Can someone recommend me a TTS solution in PHP for a CentOs server?

Tags: php, text-to-speech

i own a translation service and now im wanting to implement a TTS solution. Do you know any software that can be executed from php to generate mp3s on the fly for a specific text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in an environment where you can make system calls, you could pipe the output of [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) into [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) like so:

```
<?php
$infile = tempnam();
file_put_contents($input, 'My name is judge');

$outfile = "/path/to/output.mp3";
$cmd = "text2wave -f 22050 < {$infile} | lame --quiet --preset medium  - {$outfile}";

$output = $status = null;
exec($cmd, $output, $status);
```

If you want to do further processing as well as the conversion, you can pipe the output of text2wave to [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) instead, which can also do the conversion for you:

```
text2wave -f 22050 < input.txt | sox - output.mp3
```

The default Festival voice seems to be a bit pants though, so [this article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=751169) might be worth investigating, but I haven't actually tried it myself.

I know you aren't using ubuntu but for others who might find this answer helpful, there is a problem where even after you install all the "ugly" plugins, SoX still cannot output MP3 files. You have to manually dismantle the .deb and modify the debian/rules file to remove --without-lame from DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS.